# Flutter type of carousel z-index

Tags: flutter, user-interface, slider, z-index

I have a problem with this design
[image]

I'm trying to make this design of carousel,
I have tried PageView and AnimatedContainer, the carousel_slider package but I don't have find what I need.
I have just make this
[image]